# Forex trading gone wrong?

Tags: trading, foreign-exchange, profitability

I started forex trading a month ago and profits are like very high, I went from 120$ to 2500$! And I am finding it quite easy actually.. People everywhere are saying 90% traders fail etc etc so what am I doing wrong here? I trade at 1:1000 leverage, can anyone guide me on this? Thanks

Comment: 1:1000 leverage? Wow, you have an immense tolerance for risk. You are aware you are risking more than just your investment, right?

Comment: One black swan event and he's toast.

Comment: I put a stop loss at 100 pips, and so far 80-85% times I have made profits, so how am I risking it all kindly enlighten me I am a newbie I agree

Comment: "I started forex trading a month ago" - give it time and you'll learn, probably the hard way.

Comment: Stop losses are no guarantee of anything, one flash crash (look up the pound crash last year) and you are destroyed. I'm also curious what broker is letting someone entirely new to trading take on 1:1000 leverage

Comment: Koen thanks for letting me know, I use fxtm and fbs there are a lot of brokers giving more than that, so what's your solution to flash crashes?

Comment: At 1:1000 leverage, a loss of 0.1% [which may or may not be 100 basis points, depending on which currency pair you're talking about] is equal to a loss of 100% of your equity.

Comment: Related: https://money.stackexchange.com/a/67265/17718

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Think about it like this:

Assume 1,500 people go to a casino to play roulette. They all put their money on a single number, with 1/38 odds. On average, 39 of those people will win, giving them a payout of 36x. Then, all of those people put their money down again. On average, about 1 of those people will win again, giving them a new payout of 36x [for a total payout of 1,296x their initial investment].

Which of those people is most likely to post about their gambling results? The person who won. This is called 'survivorship bias'. It means that we are more likely to hear from people who 'survived', even though most people who played actually lost.

So in this case, you might be considered a 'survivor' of 2 months of fx trading. You seem to be invincible, and can never lose - what were all those people warning you about?! Well really, you have just defied the odds. Don't let your success blind you to the risk that was taken in that success.

Answer (score 10):

There are a few issues at play here. In the stock market, there are gains to be had over the long term. In other words, the system is not "zero sum." Forex is the buying or selling of exchange contracts pitting the value of one currency against another. For sake of discussion, let's ignore commissions. That make this zero sum. In other words, the money you make is not based on widget sales at Acme Corp, but just the misfortune of the guy on the other side of the trade. No judgement here, just facts. I clipped this years ago -

[image]

The top broker IB, brags that 46.5% of current accounts are profitable. This number contain the trail of survivor bias. i.e. traders that have lost all their money are likely to have closed their accounts. Over the long term, the average forex trader has no trading gain or loss, save for the commission. It's no more complicated than that.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I understand what you're saying but my brokers are fbs and fxcm and they are an stp broker hence my profits doesn't result in their losses.

Comment: You don't understand my answer. The losses are for the other trader, the one who took the opposite position than you.

Comment: Have you being fx trading for a long time? If so what do you recommend I should do, the reason I am here is because I know I maybe getting lucky too

Comment: I haven't traded Forex in over 30 years. It's not an investment, it's a gamble. My gambling is confined to stock options.

Comment: The relevant press release: [Interactive Brokers Leads Industry in Percentage of Profitable Customer Forex Accounts](https://www.businesswire.com/news/home/20130206005103/en/Interactive-Brokers-Leads-Industry-in-Percentage-of-Profitable-Customer-Forex-Accounts)

Comment: Wow. So in '17 I found an ad I clipped from a copy of Barron's, and you just found the original article, showing the data is from Q4 2012. I think I'm impressed.

Comment: @JTP-ApologisetoMonica The image you posted makes a powerful statement; it made a deep impression on me.

Comment: @JTP-ApologisetoMonica Do you know where to get similar tables for recent years?

Comment: No idea. I suppose a bit of searching might find a more current one, but 10 minutes of that just now turned up nothing.