# Forex trading with a specific website

Tags: foreign-exchange, scams

I am considering to start trading Forex and registered on a specific website (capitalhall.com) They are promising me huge gains and I would like to identify if they are legitimate. What are the things that I can do to verify this?

They installed MetaTrader4 on my pc and are guiding me through it using AnyDesk.

P.S. This question has been modified many times. My complete story with the company Capital Hall is now [an answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/102083/71981).

Comment: Get out now while you can.  Do not authorize anymore trades.  If you continue, your money will be gone.

Comment: It may be like the Hotel California: You can check out any time you like but your money can never leave!

Comment: You should ask yourself why they needed to install stuff on *your* computer when they're the ones making the trades. Time to wipe your computer, do a fresh install of your operating system, and change all your passwords.

Comment: Is this a scam question, or a forex question? If forex, read https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/84143/forex-trading-gone-wrong/84144#84144 else, I’d only do any business with a local US based broker.

Comment: @ceejayoz they used AnyDesk to show me how MetaTrader works. I watched what they did closely.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer I used to trade forex and, bluntly, US based brokers were absolutely awful. For example, last I checked, not a single US broker offered straight through processing. And not a single one allowed you to execute multiple strategies without separating capital per strategy. Many had rules that said if they deemed your strategy impermissible (somehow, by undefined rules) they could take any amount of your money them deemed reasonable. Foreign brokers didn't have these kinds of rules. However, it was hard to know how shady they may have been. Use only US based brokers = no forex at all.

Comment: This sounds really shady to me. A trader doing a few trades with your money to show you easy it is to make money sounds really wrong. If it was a trade in a test account with play money to show you how to do some trades that happened to make money, that's fine. (Note that those are almost never realistic!) But if this was a show with your money, that's just not how real brokers, or real forex, works. You can't just quickly make a bunch of money unless you just happen to get very lucky, which is gambling. Strategy and risk management come first. There aren't generic good trades all can take.

Comment: @Harre - I edited the question. First, I added the tag 'scams' because that seems to be the question, whether the broker is legit. Forex aside, one can ask a scam question about any business or potential transaction. Best before the fact, but, better late than never. I appreciate the 'TLDR' but not needed. The question was brief enough, the summary up top wasn't really helpful. Last note that comments are intended to clarify questions or answers, and are likely to be cleaned up at some point.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer Thanks, I edited the question some more. I removed the company name since I don't want to give them a bad name without due process. I re-added some details about how they trade, hopefully someone with knowledge about Forex trading is able to say something about this. I'd rather have the whole question closed actually since I feel that it is badly worded and should be asked in specific separate questions.

Comment: @Harre - There seem to be 2 questions - Is this a scam? And Can I go negative, and owe money? I'd suggest editing this one to narrow it to one of those 2 questions, and ask the other, in a new question.

Comment: *and this has increased to over $1600 now* **On your bank account?** I guess not, and that it's just displayed in their software.

Comment: @Jan Doggen this $1600 is in MT4.

Comment: @Hara Can you please update us what happened to your case? I have had the same experience with this broker. I deposited 2250 Euro. Now I am at 3300 Euro but now it is 10 day I am trying to withdraw my deposited money (2250 Eueo) but they are refusing to refund ...

Comment: @user77830 Since my last withdrawal I haven't tried to withdraw anything. The guy who is my broker did not make any more trades and kept asking me to invest more, which I refused. I asked him to have a conversation about what is going on and then he said that he has things going on in his private life that are causing him to be unresponsive. I decided to wait and see what happens but I'm quite skeptical at the moment.
What I told when I asked for a withdrawal is say that I am thinking about investing big money and want to make sure that I can withdraw before I make another deposit.

Comment: @Harre: You have to be aware that, if they provided the installs your MT4 program instance can show any value they like. The goal is usually to make you greedy and wait until you invest much more before you loose it all!

Comment: @Daniel thanks for the tip, I will be very careful. Does this also apply if I downloaded MT4 from the official website? And when I look at the graphs and the trade history it appears very similar to the charts that I see on other sources. (at least, for a layman like me)

Comment: @Harre: Don´t know exactly but I know it is a common scam to provide modified MT4 versions to show the victims whatever the Scammer wants. It really does not matter - if you can´t trust the Broker, you can´t trust any business that comes his way anyways. You have to ask yourself: If somebody can make a 40% return in a matter of some minutes - why is he wasting his time with your petty $250 and not moving billions for the big guys?

Comment: @Daniel I thought maybe he has smaller and larger clients, and he is hoping that I will deposit more? He said to me that I have to invest more because right now for him it is like charity work (5% of the withdrawals so he made about $55 for spending at least 15-30 minutes on me every day for 4-5 weeks). Even for a scam that sounds not really profitable.

Comment: This has become quite a story, and less easy to read. Can you move all text about what happened and that led you to the conclusion that this is a scam **into an answer**, then just leave a link to your own answer at the bottom of your question? (Links to answers are under *share*).

Comment: @JanDoggen I will do that. Do you think I should include the name of the broker or leave it out?

Comment: @Harre Obvious scammers should be named

Comment: @JanDoggen but I have no proof. I tried to record it and make screenshots but they don't show anything meaningful

Comment: Finding a normal, everyday, stockbroker is as difficult as finding like Walmart or Ford or Apple.  For hell's sake, just use an ordinary brand brokerage.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question has been edited so much, it has rendered the existing answers obsolete.

Comment: Is it? The answers are somewhat specific to the company I mentioned but could also be taken as general advice. I would hate it if someone else made the same mistake as I did because they did not have this information.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer I added a couple of extra points to my question to make it relate to the answers that are given before modification. Is there anything else I can do to make the question more useful?

Comment: I've reopened the question, and locked it from further edits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per their [website](https://capitalhall.com/contact-us/), they are located in the Marshall Islands, which means they're effectively an unregulated, off-shore broker

> Capital Tech ltd.
>
> Ajeltake Road, Ajeltake Island, Majuro republic, Marshal Islands

The CFTC warns against [Foreign Exchange Currency Fraud](https://www.cftc.gov/ConsumerProtection/FraudAwarenessPrevention/ForeignCurrencyTrading/cftcnasaaforexalert.html)

> How do the scams work?
>
> Forex scams attract customers with sophisticated-sounding offers placed in newspaper advertisements, radio promotions, or on Internet sites. Promoters often lure investors with the concept of leverage: the right to “control” a large amount of foreign currency with an initial payment representing only a fraction of the total cost. Coupled with predictions about supposedly inevitable increases in currency prices, these contracts are said to offer huge returns over a short time, with little or no downside risk.
>
> In a typical case, investors may be assured of reaping tens of thousands of dollars in just a few weeks or months, with an initial investment of only $5,000. Often, the investor’s money is never actually placed in the market through a legitimate dealer, but simply diverted—stolen— for the personal benefit of the con artists.

Even if they don't take off with your money, your trades are still unlikely to be profitable in the long run. Retail traders are at a severe disadvantage when it comes to FX trading.

If I were you, I'd try to liquidate the account and save my money or use a reputable broker to invest in a broad-market ETF.

Comment: Thanks! Begin an unregulated broker, does this mean that they can take my funds from my MetaTrader account at will or is there a third party involved?

Comment: @Harre It means that you have little to no recourse when things go wrong.

Comment: @Harre as an aside, that also applies to BTC...

Comment: Thank you for explaining. I am leaning towards taking the risk as long as I cannot lose more than my initial investment. I will post the results here for other potential traders.

Comment: @Harre please don't take this the wrong way but your questions suggest that you don't know what you're doing. You don't seem to realize that the risks you're taking have nothing to do with market risk. You're not trading, you're gambling.

Comment: how would you explain the difference between trading and gambling in this case?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82985/discussion-between-harre-and-0xfee1dead).

Comment: @Harre [Gambling is nothing more than luck](https://www.dummies.com/personal-finance/investing/day-trading/differences-between-trading-investing-and-gambling/)

Comment: @Harre I don't have anything further to add to this discussion

Comment: @Harre There are at least two ways you can lose more than your initial investment. One is if your leveraged currency loses more value than your collateral. Some brokers forgive this but others will collect it. I don't know your broker's policy. The other is some of your internal fund movements are subject to claw back. For example, you can invest $1,500, be up to $5,000, drop down to $1,500 and your $5,000 be subject to clawback, putting you at a $3,500 loss. Though unlikely, this can theoretically happen if an unregulated broker goes bankrupt.

Comment: @David Schwartz Thanks! I will check their policy and be very careful not to go into debt.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz The other option of course is that this is a scam and the money is not invested at all

Comment: @Eric how would a scam work if they can show me on MT4 what they are doing and they are making real trades?

Comment: @Harre The MT4 client is connected to their scamming server. The server can just outright be programmed to ensure your trades make a profit or the server can be just slightly better in trade execution than the real server is. By the way, most brokers test environments (even honest ones!) give much better trade execution than real environments do because they don't emulate things like slippage, partial fills, skips, and so on.

Comment: @David Schwartz Thanks, that is something I can check (I guess?). Does every broker have their own server or are they normally connected to a shared system?

Comment: @Harre - How could Bernie Madoff have been scamming people  when all of his client's account statements were showing healthy profits month after month???  :->)

Comment: Every broker has their own server. I guess you could check the prices and timestamps of the trades against a public source of FOREX trades. But I don't see much point. You don't have any sensible strategy or risk policy, so you're not in any position to trade. I'd suggest you see if you can get your money back.

Comment: @David Schwartz For as far as I can see the graphs/prices on their server are the same as on other sources. I will make periodic withdrawals and see how much I will get back. Will post here what happens.

Answer (score 10):

- I did not sign a contract
- I had to upload ID documents and a monetary statement.
- I researched them online but could find nothing of substance
- The comments were all good.
- Can I check this brokers track record somewhere?

It's possible that they may be legit but based on your statements, it sounds very likely that  they are not. Your skipped your due diligence and went right to "Show me the money!".

In the US, we can check on brokers at https://brokercheck.finra.org/

Find out where this firm is located and check with the regulatory agency in charge in that country to see what's up.

You can also try to close your account and get your money.  That will be very telling as to whether this is legit or you have been scammed.

Comment: When I search them on Google all I find is review sites like this: http://signal-means-profits.com/capitalhall-a-broker-for-risk-free-trading/
like I said the comments are positive but how do I know these are not bots?
I cannot find them in a list, not on broker check at least. Don't know where to search instead. They are located on the Marshall Islands.
Thanks for helping out btw!

Comment: I made a withdrawal right after I made the first trade, to check if they would allow that, and they did. For me that was the check that they are probably a legitimate business.

Comment: My biggest worry though is not losing my money but going into debt for an amount much bigger than my investment. With the volume of the trades this seems unlikely to me, but how can they make so much money so fast if there is not a huge risk involved?

Comment: A partial withdrawal may mean that they are legitimate or it may be their way of giving you a false sense of security and psychologically convincing you that they are legit.  Time will tell and good luck.  I hope that you make millions! ;->).

Comment: If you don't know what you are trading or  the risk involved in trading it (going into debt) then you shouldn't be trading it.

Comment: Thanks! They told me I cannot/will not go into debt, and if I am below my initial investment I will just lose what I deposited. But they seem to have no written statement of that or I did not see it.
I asked a friend who is an accountant and he said if I didn't sign anything I should not be able to go into debt.
I hope I will make millions too :D

Comment: This came right after I read Think & Grow Rich so I thought I should give it a try to see what happens :p

Comment: @Harre no offense, but you should focus on the "think" part first, and the "grow rich" part second...

Answer (score 6):

In the end I discovered that I had better listened to what the others had to say. All the answers to this post were ment to help me, although I was too stubborn and continued.

I have come to the conclusion that I have been scammed. The broker was manipulating the trades server side, there seem to be various tools for that. 
More info here:

[Is my Forex broker manipulating my trades?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/102084/is-my-forex-broker-manipulating-my-trades/102135#102135)

I will post my story here for those who are on the same path:

I started Forex trading with Capital Hall. They guided me through installing MetaTrader4 using the tool AnyDesk to control my pc and show me what trades to do.

My first deposit was $250 which quickly rose to $350 so I withdrew $50 to test if they would let me. Then I deposited $1000 and the total amount reached quickly to $2100. I would get a call from this guy daily where he instructs me to buy NAS100 or UsOil or some other commodity.

At this point I started becoming suspicious because this went all too well. I researched the company online and found only positive reviews. I read their documents and it said I could not go into debt, what the employees told me as well. I posted this question here and asked friends what they thought and everyone told me it's a scam. So I thought I should try to withdraw using a story about a friend who wanted to invest but first see me withdraw $1000.

The $1000 was nicely withdrawn into my Bitcoin wallet, but now the guy started asking me to deposit more funds which I didn't. At a certain point he would not call me or send me WhatsApp messages anymore, except sometimes when he asked me to please deposit everal thousands promising I would have it returned and doubled in a few days. Then he told me that he has a situation in his private life and I did not hear from him for some time.

After some time I got called by another guy who said he was going to continue the trading from the point where his colleague had stopped. Quickly my $1100 rose to about $1650 and I was quite happy.

Then he explained to me that with more credit I would be making money even quicker. And that his company was making a special offer because it was the end of the month and if I would deposit $2000 now I would get $4000 worth of credits. When I declined at first he reduced his offer to 'deposit $1000 and get $2000 credit' which I took.

So I deposited $1000 and he told me to buy a stock. This time the trade would quickly drop to $-1500. After the weekend he called me again and said he has a huge opportunity if I deposited $3000 now. I eventually agreed to deposit $1500 instead and got $3000 in credits. Then we bought another stock which then dropped to $-5000 while the total balance reached $-8000.

Now I got a call from this guy again and later his friend saying that I have to deposit $2500 now to save my account. I almost tried to transfer more but this went wrong. Now this guy and his friend kept calling me and he wants to login to my crypto wallets. He says that I have to call my friends and family to borrow their money. When I kept saying that I would not do that he hung up on me. My account was then closed.

Later I discovered that there were scam warnings about this company:
https://www.forexbrokerz.com/brokers/capital-hall-review
https://theforexreview.com/2018/11/09/capital-hall-review/

Lost almost $3000.

Comment: Wow.  Thanks for coming back and posting your story here; it'll hopefully be a useful warning to others tempted by similar offers.

Comment: @Aaaargggh did you seriously just un-accept my answer to accept your own?!

Comment: @0xFEE1DEAD it was per accident. I came back after a while, had a quick glance at it and thought I saw no accepted answer. I made your answer the accepted one again.